# VB.net Changing application argv parameters on runtime

Tags: c#, vb.net, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to change app argument on runtime?

I have simple application used inside my organisation that gets specific data about PDF file (opened in somekind of viewer). By now, I'm using SlimPDF for PDF viewing, because it's possible to open each document in new windows - and so - have different argv(0) on each on it.

I'm trying to implement my own PDF viewer, that will change it's argument, depending on file that is currently opened. Viewer will work on tabs, so when user changes tab - argv(0) should also change that my app can read currently viewed file.

I see that `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` can only output arguments, not set them.

What is the correct way to solve this problem? It it actually possible to change argv on runtime in VB.net / C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Commandlineargs is defined outside the application (for example in the shortcut) and is only used at start -up. Once the application has been launched, it has no uses for any more and is only informational. The only possibility is to modify the shortcut from the app and the change will apply during the next start.

Comment: Once the application is started, it's really no point changing the command line *Launch* arguments.  Are you launching instance of another app maybe and that is the command line args you're looking to change?  Your question probably needs a lot more detail of exactly what you are doing, rather than just a project overview